# System.IO.IOException: 'The target file is a directory, not a file.'

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to copy an image that was selected using the open file dialog tool, but it keeps throwing me the error
 `System.IO.IOException: 'The target file "C:\Users\Anthony\Documents\\yes" is a directory, not a file.'`.
This is my code for that section.

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Title = "Select Background Image";
    ofd.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png;)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png;";
    ofd.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
    {
        label15.Text = ofd.FileName;
        FileInfo i = new FileInfo(ofd.FileName);
        i.CopyTo(@"C:\Users\Anthony\Documents\\" + label1.Text);
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could the errormessage be more precise? Try to paste that path into a file explorer ...

Comment: Well it sounds like you're trying to copy to a directory, not a file. If `yes` already exists, and is a directory, what did you expect to happen, and what have you done to try to implement that behavior?

Comment: What's with the extra backslash in the path? Also, may be better to consider the functions provided by `Path` for combining file paths rather than using naive string concatenation.

Comment: I also recommend using [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of string-concatenation.

Comment: jon skeet , yes is infact a file so im really unsure is just wanted the image to be in that folder hahah

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to copy the file to `label1.Text`. Sounds like the label on the yes button.

Comment: You cannot just give a folder for a target. It has to be a file. Filename can be the same as the source file, but it won't automatically be added if just providing a folder path.

Comment: could you give me an example

Comment: Are you sure that you did not miss the file extension when `yes` really is a file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the full path for `CopyTo`

```
i.CopyTo(Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\Anthony\Documents", label1.Text, i.FileName));
```